# UML - Hybrid between component and activity diagrams

Tags: uml

I currently work on a rather large system that consists of a WinForms app that uses WCF services and a database at the bottom. If you think about a use case or a requirement, what a developer needs is a quick overview of the implementation of that particular use case (or requirement). A person who knows the systems could very quickly verbally explain that these two views (or subviews) are used in the UI, they are data-bound to this controller, which uses this WCF service to get this DTO. The service uses this business class, which uses this data adapter, and the data is in these tables in the database.

I think in most cases it would be possible to convey all this information in a single diagram. However, it would be a kind of a hybrid between component and activity diagrams as it shows both workflow and the components that are involved. UML obviously doesn't have such a diagram, but I was wondering if anyone has done anything on these lines and what tools you have used.

Comment: Just a comment to your topic. If you are interested in UML and other OMG languages (Model Driven Architecture) we are trying to set up a specific Question Asnwering website. You are invited to follow this group at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36533/model-driven-architecture and post your questions there (also). Bye!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think activity diagram is appropriate here. Activity diagrams, as far as i believe are intended for somebody to understand how the module/system works without getting into the technical part. But then if you can express all that what you said in an activity digram and if your team and your audience are able to decipher things, then sure. Getting back to your scenario, i have done this before and a UML sequence diagram has helped me here. A sequence diagram depicts sequential object interactions. You might wanna check it out

Comment: Thanks, Hari. I do use sequence diagrams for more low-level documentation, usually generated from code. It has never even occured to me to use sequence diagrams for more abstract constructs. I'll have to try it out. How do you depict data-binding?

Comment: Not sure what technology you use. ASP>NET MVC and MVPC where i usually have an IView with a method called SetBindingSource which would be called by my presenter which then passes the model to the the SetBindingSource method. In the concrete view implementation, atleast in .NET databinding is as simple assigning the model to a bindable property of the control. But to be honest, i am surprised that Presentation level details are being shown in the sequence digram. Or a lot of people can be surprised to find out that i dont show GUI level details in sequence diagrams.

Comment: I generally dont show that because i believe that its not worth the time to design GUI level details upfront. Sure it makes sense to reverse engineer and document them. But presentation layer generally is susceptible to a lot of change and synchronizing the artifacts becomes a head ache.